# Meaning of go around in the sentence

Tags: sentence, sentence-meaning

I am trying to understand the meaning of go around in following sentence.

After checking the dictionary, I found 2 possible meanings.

> 1. spin
> 2. a flight path taken by an aircraft after an aborted approach to landing.

Could you please help me understand its meaning in the sentence below? Please let me know if more information is required.

**Sentence**

Frustrated, she and her friend found that there were not enough instruments to go around

**Screenshot of the full paragraph**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic sense is the following:

***[Go around](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-around):***

> (INTRANSITIVE) to be enough so that everyone can have one or some.
>
> ***be enough to go around***: *In some classes, there aren’t even enough books to go around.*

(Macmillan Dictionary)

They are saying that there were not enough instruments for everybody.

Comment: I am grateful for this answer, I was trying to search *go around* on google but did not think to search with  *enough go around*. Thank you sir